# Android’s New Image Capture from a Camera using File Provider and saving in root directory

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, android-camera2, android-camera-intent

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xar0u.png)i am working on App in which i take pictures from camera, and save that picture in root directory of android,  everything is working fine the problem that i am facing is with its name , when the file is getting save the function in Concatenating  extra Number with it,

@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
private File getImageFile() throws IOException {

```
    timeTicks = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMMyyyy_hhmmss-").format(new Date());
    imageName = "img-" + timeTicks;  //30Nov2021_105137-
    storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    imageFile = File.createTempFile(imageName, ".jpg", storageDir); //storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.meterreadingrecord/files/Pictures/img-30Nov2021_105137-3304015006530902745.jpg
    imageName = imageFile.getName();
    currentImagePath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
    return imageFile;
    return imageFile;
}
```

3304015006530902745.jpg This extra Time tick is getting concatinate with the file name that i am creating,

Anyone can help me this?? please

Thanks alot in advance

Comment: Why are you using `createTempFile` if you don't want the [file name format of `createTempFile`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File#createTempFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File))

Comment: Do not create the file youraelf. Just make a File object: `File imageFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PUCTURES), fileName);`

Comment: that is the function creating image file

Comment: if (cameraIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                imageFile = null;
                try {
                    imageFile = getImageFile();

Comment: private File getImageFile() throws IOException {


        timeTicks = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMMyyyy_hhmmss-").format(new Date());
        imageName = "img-" + timeTicks;
        storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        imageFile = File.createTempFile(imageName, ".jpg", storageDir);
        imageName = imageFile.getName();
        currentImagePath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
        return imageFile;
    }

Comment: This is complete code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in [blackapps](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12121419/blackapps) comment, using

```
File imageFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PUCTURES), fileName);
```

instead of

```
imageFile = File.createTempFile(imageName, ".jpg", storageDir);
```

solves the problem.